# How do I do a for loop in SQL using Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I have a Basic Background in Python and my knowledge of SQL is growing, but I have never done anything with Loops in SQL.
I want to do a for Loop in SQL using a list and do so in pgAdmin 4.

So coming from a Python perspective I want to translate the
"for l in list" Statement into SQL.

I have been researching a lot online already, but I can't find a tutorial or manual that explains step by step how it works and what each word or part in the Statement does.

Is there a Website, Manual, tutorial or even a book you can recommend, that is good for a beginner in SQL Loops? Or can someone maybe explain it in an answer comment here, if it's not too complex and long to do so?

Based on my research on Loops in SQL so far, here is an example of what I am trying to do might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE draft AS
FOR x IN list [green1, blue2, red4]
LOOP
-- do this and that --
END LOOP;
```

Comment: You might not need a loop here; maybe a query would suffice.  Can you tell us why you need a loop?

Comment: Hi, I need a loop in order to apply the same set of statements/queries to each item in the list and I have over 50 items in my list.

Comment: What exactly is "this and that"? SQL is a set processing language and it is very unusual to think in "loops". Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: SQL is declarative language, not algorithmic

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with PL/SQL to loop an array.

```
declare
   type draft_arr_type is table of  draft%rowtype index by pls_integer;
   v_draft_arr draft_arr_type;
begin
   SELECT *
      bulk collect into v_draft_arr
      FROM draft
      ORDER BY <what you want here>;

   for i in v_draft_arr.first..v_draft_arr.last loop
      --code
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have loops, You have to use PL/pgSQL, In order to write loops.

Check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS